# Show Package Content option not available in High Sierra on a pkg file

Tags: high-sierra, dmg, pkg

I want to "Show Package Content" of a pkg file which is inside this dmg file : https://desktop.visio.renater.fr/scopia/entry/pic/ClientComponents.dmg

So I drag'n'drop the pkg file which is inside the dmg to the "Desktop" folder.

Then I right click on the pkg file and here is what I see :

[image]

Can you help ?

Comment: Have you searched this site for answers that already exist for similar questions (such as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15665/88313))?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368534/313842 Pacifist

Comment: @ankii Pacifist is shareware, I prefer to use opensource or free software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Show Package Contents is used to show the contents of an application. If you go to an application on you mac and right click on it, you get a menu and one option is to "Show Package Contents". This applies to apps.

There is a way to show the contents of a pkg file but you must do it using the terminal.  Just type the following command: `pkgutil --expand /path/to/package.pkg /output/destination/`. A description of this is given [here](https://becomethesolution.com/blogs/mac/pkg-no-show-package-contents).

Comment: RE: "This applies to apps." While it does apply to .app files, it also applies to .bundle, .framework, .plugin, .kext, and so on and document bundles as well. Have a look at: [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html) -- A `filename.pkg` file is not a _directory_, but a _binary file_ and why the **Show Package Contents** _command_ isn't available for it.